# Alternative to document.open when using getElementById?

Tags: javascript, element

I used to use `document.write()` instead of using `document.getElementById()`, when I used `document.write()` I could openly use `document.open()` which meant that I could have different pages but still staying on the same page (.html). I've tried many things such as hiding the elements but that makes the links on them still clickable.

I would like the achieve the same things but while still using good practise.

Here is what I used to do;

```
document.write("Hey!");
document.write('<button onclick="bye()">');

function bye() {
    document.open()
    // Clears page
    document.write("Bye");
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code of the two different examples?

Comment: @zero298 There you go!

Comment: Are you asking how to add elements to a page without clearing the page?  Or how to remove an element from a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to append elements and remove them from a page without having to use `document.write`, you can do so using `document.createElement()`

Consider this example:

The `add` button will create a `div` and then append it to another `div` in the page called `target`.  `remove` will remove the first child element of the `target` `div`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Div Controller</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script>
         function main() {
            document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
               var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
               newDiv.innerHTML = "I'm a div";
               document.getElementById("target").appendChild(newDiv);
            });
            document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function() {
               var target = document.getElementById("target");
               if (target.firstChild) {
                  target.removeChild(target.firstChild);
               }
            });
         }

         window.onload = main;
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="target"></div>
      <button id="add">Add</button>
      <button id="remove">Remove</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write()`. Instead, I'd just use `document.body.innerHTML` to `""`, and append things to the `innerHTML`, like this

```
function bye(){
     document.body.innerHTML=""; //clears page
     document.body.innerHTML+="Bye";
}
```

or you could combine the two into

```
document.body.innerHTML="Bye";
```